# InvalidArgumentException: Class ... does not exist in custom configuration form

Tags: forms, 9

I create configuration form, so that I could dynamically set the API key for my custom weather module.

But when I write in the url address `http://drupalsite/admin/config/services/weather/settings` I get the error:

> InvalidArgumentException: Class "\Drupal\weather\Form\WeatherSettingsForm" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ClassResolver->getInstanceFromDefinition() (line 24 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/ClassResolver.php).

I checked the Class Name and File name and cleared the caches but the error did not go away.
How to fix it?

**weather.routing.yml**

```
weather.weather_page:                               
  path: '/weather/{city}'
  defaults:                                                       
    _controller: '\Drupal\weather\Controller\WeatherPage::getWeather'                          
  requirements:                                        
     _permission: 'access content'
weather.settings:
  path: '/admin/config/services/weather/settings'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\weather\Form\WeatherSettingsForm'
    _title: 'Weather Settings form'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer site configuration'
```

**WeatherSettingsForm.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\weather\Form;         

use Drupal\Core\Form\ConfigFormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Configure example settings for this site.
 */
class WeatherSettingsForm extends ConfigFormBase {      
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'weather_admin_settings';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function getEditableConfigNames() {
    return [
      'weather.settings',
    ];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $config = $this->config('weather.settings');

    $form['weather_api_key'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('API Key'),
      '#default_value' => $config->get('weather_api_key'),
    );

    return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $this->configFactory->getEditable('weather.settings')
      ->set('weather_api_key', $form_state->getValue('weather_api_key'))
      ->save();

    parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Assuming your module’s machine name is `weather`, move the form class to `module_path/src/Form/`

Comment: @Clive Excuse me, maybe I didn't understand you, but you say that I need to move the `WeatherSettingsForm.php` file which contains the `WeatherSettingsForm` class to a folder `modules/custom/weather/src/Form` ? But this file is there:
https://i.postimg.cc/KYqv3NYp/sc.png

Comment: I ran the code as posted and it works for me, so maybe you have a typo somewhere locally, or maybe a hidden character got in somewhere.

Comment: @Lambic On which version of drupal did you run the code?

Comment: We're on version 9.1

Comment: @Lambic I found a solution to the problem, I just had to restart the docker4drupal.

Comment: add $settings['class_loader_auto_detect'] = FALSE;  to local.settings.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution:

I just needed to restart the **docker4drupal**.

When I wrote the commands:

```
docker-compose stop
docker-compose up -d
```

The error is gone.

Comment: Did you not clear the cache after making changes? Restarting web servers is (extremely rare) for development.

Comment: @Kevin yes, of course, I cleared cache after making changes.

Comment: Something else is wrong or happened then, because a server restart to see changes is not normal, unless you enabled the module (registering the class paths) and then moved some files. That sometimes may require a restart to wipe the class path cache.

Comment: Lost an half an hour with this :( Thank you a lot

Comment: Hard to imagine, but the same approach worked for me in my Lando-based local dev: I did a 'lando restart' and the class resolver could find my class.

Comment: Wow, same thing here.  It was driving me crazy because the code looked perfect!  Required a lando restart.

Comment: I never would have worked this out. I was getting the "The [entity] entity type did not specify a [action] form class" error, hacked EntityTypeManager to find the real reason was that the form class "didn't exist" - when it did, but I'd previously made a mistake in the entity definition that no amount of module reinstalls or cache clears would fix. Eventually a `lando restart` was the only thing that worked.

Comment: Also read: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3342669